# Where are the constant solutions of this separable ODE $y'=y^2-4$.?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y'=y^2-4$.

We can solve this equation by separation of variables, and thus we reach the solutions

> $$y(x) = -\frac{2 (e^{4 c_1 + 4 x} - 1)}{e^{4 c_1 + 4 x} + 1}$$

(Checked using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3Dy%5E2-4))

Now, we can see plainly that the constant solutions $y=\pm 2$ satisfy the equations. Are this solutions hidden in this formula for a particular value of $c_1$? If not, how can I make the integration such that the constant solutions are not lost?

Comment: Your lost solutions correspond to $c_1=+\infty$ and $c_1=-\infty$.  In your solution, did you divide by $y^2-4$?  If so, you should have a second case $y^2-4=0$ in addition.

Comment: @GEdgar I did! This makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lost solutions correspond to $c_1=+\infty$
and $c_1=−\infty$. In your solution, did you divide by $y^2−4$? 
If so, you should have a second case $y^2−4=0$
 in addition.